# Import a cert to existing Keystore

Tags: import, cert

I want to import a cert as privatekeyentry to existing keystore.jks and unable to do so , i tried below

keytool -import -alias devtest-ft1 -keystore Keystore.jks -file devtest-cert

the above command worked but it has added as trustedCertEntry, but I am after PrivateKeyEntry
but its adding as trustedCertEntry which is not a right format , any help is appreciated

Comment: Certificates do not include private keys.